# Detect touch on a subview of a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, touch, subview

I'm creating an app with Swift with a menu.

On this menu, there is a button which reveals a view. On this view, there is a button.

This is my view :

```
    let buyHotModeViewHeight = screenHeight * 0.8
    let buyHotModeViewWidth = modesWidth

    let buyHotModeView = BuyHotModeView(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth / 2 - buyHotModeViewWidth / 2, y: screenHeight / 2 - buyHotModeViewHeight / 2, width: buyHotModeViewWidth, height: buyHotModeViewHeight))
    view.addSubview(buyHotModeView)
```

This is the button on the view :

```
    // MARK: BUY HOT MODE BUTTON

    let buyHotModeButtonWidth = frame.width / 4
    let buyHotModeButtonHeight = buyHotModeButtonWidth / 2

    let buyHotModeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width / 2 - buyHotModeButtonWidth / 2, y: topBackground.frame.height - buyHotModeButtonHeight * 1.5, width: buyHotModeButtonWidth, height: buyHotModeButtonHeight))
    buyHotModeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2)
    addSubview(buyHotModeButton)
```

The problem is that I can not touch this button, nothing happens (I removed the `addTarget` line for the exemple to simplify the code).

Comment: Is userInteractionEnabled on the presented view?

Comment: Can you confirm that the button's animation is happening every time you hit the button?

Comment: When I click the button, the view appears progressively (alpha from 0 to 1 during 0.4sec). I tried to set alpha to 1 directly, no animation, and it work !

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding that last comment. When you hit a button it should have some type of animation indicating it was just pressed.

Comment: There is no animation, in fact I fount the solution, on my MenuViewController, the view appears when I touch a button with an other view behind it (I use it like a black background with 0.5 in opacity). I removed this black background and it works ! Thanks ;)